# Want to seperate table border width using xslt

Tags: xslt

**Input html style::**

```
border: #5f497a 3pt solid;
     or

border: 3pt #5f497a solid;
     or

border: solid #5f497a 3pt;
```

Hi all, 
  These all are my possible html input style from which i have to fetch only the border width (3)  using xslt 1.0. Please help me..Thanks in advance..

**Note:I will have always one digit before pt**

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy XSLT 1.0 solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="table">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@style"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@style">

  <xsl:if test="string-length() >0">
    <xsl:variable name="vValues"
       select="substring-after(.,':')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vNormalized" select=
    "translate(normalize-space(concat(';',$vValues)),
               ' ',
               ';')
    "/>

    <xsl:variable name="vEndingWidth" select=
     "substring-before($vNormalized,'pt;')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vLength"
         select="string-length($vEndingWidth)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="substring($vEndingWidth, $vLength)"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
    <table style="border: #5f497a 3pt solid;"/>
    <table style="border: 3pt #5f497a solid;"/>
    <table style="border: solid #5f497a 3pt;"/>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct results:**

```
3
3
3
```